# Cross referencing a figure

Tags: cross-referencing

For citing equation, I use either of these 3 ways:

1. `\ref{eqn}` gives the out put, say, 1, which is the equation number
2. `\eqref{eqn}` in `amsmath` package will put the equation number in `()`
3. `\cref{eqn}` in `cleveref` package will give the pitput in this form `eq. (1)`, i.e. it add the letter 'eq.' and  put the equation number in brackets.

My question is there any command similar to `cleveref` with reference to figure where in they would add suffix like 'Fig.' and put the figure number in brackets? E.g. **Fig 1**

Comment: Yes, `cleveref`. It works for figures as well. (Edit: I meant of course `\cref{figurelabel}`.)

Comment: See here, for example: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing

Comment: @TorbjørnT. and CarLaTeX thanks a lot for those inputs. I didn't know it...

Comment: @CarLaTeX and TorbjørnT., if I use that cleveref if will give 'eq.' and 'fig.'. Is there any way to give generate 'Eq.' and 'Fig.'

Comment: You can use `\crefname{htypei}{hsingulari}{hplurali}`, where `htypei` is the name of the counter for the environment
(equation, chapter, section, etc.), and `hsingulari` and `hplurali` are the forms of the new name you want. See the `cleveref` package, subsection 8.1.2.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, Sorry for the delay in replying.. It worked and thanks..

Comment: @sreerajt You're welcome! And remember that the package documentation is very useful :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX, sure...